# Plain old Ruby object location in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails n00b question. I am creating a plain old Ruby object in Rails. But I am not sure if there is a standard location in the app that I should put this object.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several choices,  but the `lib` directory is the most common.

If you need to initialize the code,  the most common place is  `config/initializers`.

So you might have:

```
lib/mystuff.rb
```

and:

```
config/initializers/mystuff.rb
lib/mystuff.rb
```

contains your ruby code.

```
config/initializers/mystuff.rb
```

contains code that initializes your stuff,  whatever Ruby files that are found in `config/initializers` are run when Rails boots up.

Comment: So to access it would I just add require 'lib/my_object.rb'

Comment: Remember that only things in `app` and `config/routes.rb` are automatically reloaded between requests. For other things you'll need to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: require 'my_object'  should suffice